# How can I solve this error in Processing using the unfoldingmaps

Tags: java

This is my code

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;

import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

public class SimpleMapApp extends PApplet {

UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {
        size(750, 600,P2D);
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
    }

    public void draw() {
        map.draw();
    }

}
```

When i run it throws exception:

> Unfolding Map v0.9.6
>
> Using OpenGLMapDisplay with processing.opengl.PGraphics2D
>
> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
>   http://a.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/2/2/2.png    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)  at
>   processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(PApplet.java:7233)     at
>   processing.core.PApplet.createInput(PApplet.java:7201)    at
>   processing.core.PApplet.loadBytes(PApplet.java:7428)  at
>   processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(PApplet.java:5867)  at
>   de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.getTileFromUrl(Unknown Source)
>     at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.TileLoader.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your map provider.

```
map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
```